# a date string without year to NSDate with year

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date string of
     "5:09 pm Wed Sep 2",which is coming from server.
    when converting the string into `NSDate`.
    "2000-09-02 17:09:00 +0000" but the year should have been "2015" like:
    "2015-09-02 17:09:00 +0000"

Here is my code please let me know where is the problem

```
NSString *dateStr = @"5:09 pm Wed Sep 2";

// Convert string to date object
NSString *dateFormat=  ([self hasAMPM])?@"hh:mm a EEEE MMM d":@"hh:mm a EEEE MMM d" ;
    NSDate * date = [self toLocalTime:[self convertDateFromString:dateStr OutputFormat:dateFormat]];


///****
-(BOOL)hasAMPM{
    NSString *formatStringForHours = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"j" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

    NSRange containsA = [formatStringForHours rangeOfString:@"a"];
    BOOL hasAMPM = containsA.location != NSNotFound;
    return hasAMPM;
}

-(NSDate *)toLocalTime:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    NSInteger seconds = [tz secondsFromGMTForDate: date];
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: seconds sinceDate: date];
}

-(NSDate *)convertDateFromString:(NSString *)strDate OutputFormat:(NSString *)outPutFormat
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:outPutFormat];

    NSDate *date1= [formatter dateFromString:strDate];
    return date1;
}
```

Please help me to get out of this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the year in your date according to current date, this works for dates from 1970 onwards, haven't checked for beyond that:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"5:09 pm Wed Sep 2";

NSString *dateString = [dateStr stringByAppendingString:@" 1970"];
// Convert string to date object
NSString *dateFormat=  ([self hasAMPM])?@"hh:mm a EE MMM d yyyy":@"hh:mm a EE MMM d yyyy" ;
NSDate * date = [self toLocalTime:[self convertDateFromString:dateString OutputFormat:dateFormat]];

NSCalendar *greCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
greCalendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSDateComponents *componenetsForCurrent = [greCalendar componentsInTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger year = componenetsForCurrent.year;



NSDate *requiredDate = [greCalendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear value:(year-1970) toDate:date options:NSCalendarWrapComponents];
```

Comment: Great! Then please accept it as answer! :) Helps me in return... :D

Answer (score 0):

You can split your date using NSDateComponents, and work with year independently

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
[dateComponents setYear:someYear];
date = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```