# Set NSDate to current year from String without year, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string that I am pulling from the web in the format "Sat, Jan 30 @ 11:00 AM" and want to convert this to an NSDate.  I am able to do so with the code below, but the year defaults to 2000.

How can I set the year to the current year for my NSDate?

```
                    var dateString = "Sat, Jan 30 @ 11:00 AM"

                    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM dd @ hh:mm a"

                    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

                    //date output is 2000-01-30 19:00:00 +0000
```

I believe that this is the Objective-C answer: 
"[a date string without year to NSDate with year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352451/a-date-string-without-year-to-nsdate-with-year)"

Thanks!

Comment: If that objective c version works for you, the swift implementation will be identical since it uses Foundation classes. Autocomplete is your friend.

Comment: If you have an answer in Objective-C, then what is your question since you already have an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's the best way to do it, since I am kinda new to programming. But I would do something like that, works fine I guess (I know the order is kinda confusing, but I just did this in a few minutes without making the code "look good" ^^):

```
var dateString = "Sat, Jan 30 @ 11:00 AM"

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY EEE, MMM dd @ hh:mm a"

    //let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

    let currentDate = NSDate()
    let newFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    newFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY"

    let YearString = newFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
    let newDateString = String(YearString + " " + dateString)
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(newDateString)
    print(date)
```

Comment: Your date format it is wrong `Y` it is for WeekOfYear you have to use `yyyy`

Comment: really? I wasn't sure about that but the print statement gave me how I wanted it?!

Comment: I just tried it with yyyy instead of YYYY, gave me the exact same print.. But maybe your answer is more correct, idk :-D

Comment: You are testing only with a single date in the beginning of the year

Comment: *Do not* use `YYYY`. Use `yyyy`.

Comment: @beginner_T Thanks for the answer.  Here is a link I found that might clear up the "YYYY" vs "yyyy" [http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table]

Answer (score 4):

Just add a single line of code to your dateFormatter (Swift 3)

```
var dateString = "Sat, Jan 30 @ 11:00 AM"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM dd @ hh:mm a"

dateFormatter.defaultDate = Date() // New Line

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```